# Condition in excel that would allow me to subtract the last populated cell from the first

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say I have 10 cells A1-A10 some cells may be blank how do I construct a formula with the condition that always takes A1 - the last cell populated with a value. Ex cells A1 A3 and A7 have values so it would do A1-A7 but on another sheet A1 A4 A8 are populated so it would do A1-A8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to approximate MATCH an impossibly large number will return the row number of the last cell in a column populated with a number. Paired with INDEX, you get the last number in a column.

```
=a1-index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A, 1))
'or
=a1-index(A:A, match(1e99, A:A))    ' 1 is the default [match_type] for MATCH
```

1E99 is a 1 followed by 99 zeroes (an impossibly large number).

Comment: Excel up to version 2003 supports a maximum of `65,536` rows, whereas from 2007 to current it's `1,048,576` (or `2^20` for short).

Comment: While true, that's completely irrelevant. MATCH returns a row number while looking for an impossibly large number, it doesn't look for a row number. I typically use 1E99 because it is the largest number with the fewest keystrokes. Try it and see.

Comment: Ahh, just took another look and realized I misunderstood at first glance, I thought you were specifying a blatantly large number to get the ceiling value on row position.  So in this case, `MATCH` is using argument `1` and returning the closest value ≤ 1E99?  Sorry about that.

Comment: Not the closest number. Literally the last number in a column containing numbers or numbers and text/blanks. `1, 6, 4, <blank>, 3` would return the row number containing 3. Paired with INDEX gives you the 3.

Comment: +1 for use of 1E99, this is a handy little trick I've never seen before